# set free_index for 7-dof robot's IKFast moveit plugin generation

Tags: ros, ikfast, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I writing to ask a question about setting **free joint index** for a 7-dof robot's ikfast moveit plugin generation. I am running ROS kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04 and `openrave` master branch ([commit](https://github.com/rdiankov/openrave/tree/7c5f5e27eec2b2ef10aa63fbc519a998c276f908)). The `sympy` version I am using is 0.7.1 (matching openrave;s requirement).

The 7 dof robot I am working on consists of one standard 6 dof industrial robotic arm and a horizontal linear axis. Take the following 6-axis IRB6640 + linear axis for an example, the links info is:

```
name                    index parents                
-----------------------------------------------------
base_link               0                            
linear_axis_base_link   1     base_link              
linear_axis_zero        2     linear_axis_base_link  
linear_axis_carriage    3     linear_axis_zero       
linear_axis_robot_mount 4     linear_axis_carriage   
robot_base_link         5     linear_axis_robot_mount
robot_base              6     robot_base_link        
robot_link_1            7     robot_base_link        
robot_link_2            8     robot_link_1           
robot_link_3            9     robot_link_2           
robot_link_4            10    robot_link_3           
robot_link_5            11    robot_link_4           
robot_link_6            12    robot_link_5           
robot_tool0             13    robot_link_6           
eef_base_link           14    robot_tool0            
eef_tcp_frame           15    eef_base_link          
robot_link_cylinder     16    robot_link_1           
robot_link_piston       17    robot_link_cylinder    
-----------------------------------------------------
name                    index parents
```

A snapshot of the dae visualization:

[image]

However, I've tried setting `free_index` to each of the indices, but the ikfast either popped up the following error (and I've tried running `round_collada_numbers`) or it takes 8 minutes or so to compute and then end with some errors:

> **main**.CannotSolveError: CannotSolveError: need 6 joints

My question is: What would be the role of thumb in setting up this free index in ikfast generation for our 6-index industrial robot + linear axis setup, which is quite common in many real-world industrial applications?

FYI, I have documented a lot of details in my trial-and-error in an updated ikfast tutorial dedicated to Kinetic [here](https://github.com/yijiangh/framefab_mpp/blob/bc777069b8eb7283c74af26e5461532aec3d9e8a/framefab_robot/abb/framefab_irb6600/framefab_irb6600_support/doc/ikfast_tutorial.rst) [1], in the hope that it can help others.

[1] https://github.com/yijiangh/framefab_mpp/blob/feature/abb_w_linear_track/framefab_robot/abb/framefab_irb6600/framefab_irb6600_support/doc/ikfast_tutorial.rst

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285611/set-free_index-for-7-dof-robot%27s-ikfast-moveit-plugin-generation/) by [yijiangh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28469/yijiangh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2018-03-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-16**:
This is not an answer, but see if the procedure in #q263925 makes any difference. It's written for 4dof, but just replace with the appropriate solver type. Using the `inversekinematics` database has helped me get past weird IKFast errors before. Can't guarantee anything, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Following the link in @gvdhoorn's comment above, I've successfully created ikfast plugin for my 6+1dof case, using ikfast's `inversekinematics database`.

I've documented the resolution in an updated moveit-ikfast tutorial [here](https://github.com/yijiangh/Choreo/blob/7c98fd29120e5ce75d2b8ed17bc49488ad983cb6/framefab_robot/abb/framefab_irb6600/framefab_irb6600_support/doc/ikfast_tutorial.rst) if anyone is interested in this.

---

Originally posted by [yijiangh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28469/yijiangh/) with karma: 131 on 2018-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0